# How to show toplevel window with main window when main window was clicked on taskbar and vice versa?

Tags: python, tkinter, taskbar, toplevel

I have a tkinter application that has a main window (a Tk) and an additional window (a Toplevel).

For example, now they are both behind a web browser.
I want them both shown up in front of the web browser when either one of their icon is clicked on the taskbar.

Does tkinter have this feature?

Comment: Relevant [Wm.group-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.group-method)

Comment: Also relevant [Wm.transient-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method)